# create popup screen in blackBerry

Tags: blackberry, screen

I want to create a popup screen in BlackBerry like the screen appear on long click (see the picture)[image]

My screen contain 3 items

image description

---

image description

---

image description

Can any one help me by an example or link to do this popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find the code here to create [creating-borderless-transparent-popup screen in blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/08/creating-borderless-transparent-popup.html)
2. If your looking for custmizing the Buttons as appeared in image then visit [custom-image-buttonfield-in-blackberry](http://www.codinguru.com/2011/02/custom-image-buttonfield-in-blackberry.html)
3. You have to make use of GridFieldManager.java for the layout you have used, Also you can customize your own layout.

Comment: hi Neel. I too want to create a pop up screen, same like shown above. I cant able to view the link given by you. can you put a valid link please.

Comment: Arun.. The site above is mentained by me, and is under maintenance.  plz give me few time. i am working towards its fix. if i am not able to do then i can mail u or paste the code here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code and call the GetPopup wherever you want to show the pop up screen

```
    final class Getpopup extends PopupScreen
    {
      EditField edf;
     AutoTextEditField edf1;
     HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
     public Getpopup()
    {
    super( new VerticalFieldManager());
    LabelField lf = new LabelField("Contact Info", LabelField.FIELD_HCENTER);
    SeparatorField sf = new SeparatorField(); 
    edf1= new AutoTextEditField("Name:","" ,20,EditField.NO_NEWLINE);        
    edf  = new EditField("Number:",ThirdScreen.get3);
    edf.setEditable(false);  
    VerticalFieldManager vfm =new VerticalFieldManager(VerticalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);
    hfm=new HorizontalFieldManager(HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER);  
    ButtonField bf1 = new ButtonField("Save", ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER);
    ButtonField bf2 = new ButtonField("Cancel", ButtonField.FIELD_HCENTER);
    hfm.add(bf1);
    hfm.add(bf2);
    vfm.add(lf);
    vfm.add(sf);
    vfm.add(edf1);
    vfm.add(edf); 
    vfm.add(hfm); 
    add(vfm);  
  }
  }
```

Comment: How to add an image ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a PopupDialog class which extends Dialog and then in the constructor, add the Buttons. If you would like your buttons to look like the above image, extend a field or button field and in paint method, draw the button and then the button text below the button. Add this custom button control in the PopupDialog.

Comment: The API already has its own `PopupScreen` class for that.  You do not need to derive a custom class from `Dialog`.